# Inverse of matrix product $AB^{-1}A^T$

Tags: matrices

Consider the matrices $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ (note that $A$ isn't square), $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. Assume that $A$ is full row-rank and that $B$ is positive definite and symmetric. I wish to compute:
\begin{align*}
(AB^{-1}A^T)^{-1}
\end{align*}
Is there any way to rewrite the above inverse in a more simple way?

Answer (score 0):

If $B$ is positive definite and symmetric, it can be [Cholesky factored](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_inverse) into $B = L^TL$ and it's inverse is therefore $L^{-1}L^{-T}$. If we use this we can rewrite: ${(AL^{-1}L^{-T}A^T)}^{-1}$, we see that if we write $C = AL^{-1}$ this becomes $C^{-T}C^{-1}$ which maybe is easier depending on what you want to use it for.

---

**EDIT:**
This becomes the even simpler expression $CC^T$ if we instead choose $C = ({LA^{-1}})$ above. However this of course will only make sense if we could find a reasonable way to invert $A$ ( which if we look at the problem description is non-square ). Maybe some [pseudo-inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_inverse) could help us here.

Comment: not really sure, but maybe this can help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity

Comment: But $A$ isn't invertible (it isn't square).

Comment: Oh yes you're right rogerG, didn't think of that. Then $C = AL^{-1}$ will have to do, or maybe we can try a pseudoinverse of A.